# jquery dynamic drop/drag accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I am new to javascript and jquery guys plz help,

I have a list which I drag such as

```
<ul class='drag-list'>
    <li>category 1</li>
    <li>category2</li>
    ------------
    ------------
</ul>
```

and drop it on

```
<div class='dropArea'>
    <div id="accordion"></div>
</div>
```

when I drop the list it should be converted to accordin

My drag and drop code is

```
$( ".drag-list li" ).draggable({        
    helper:"clone"
});

$( ".dropArea" ).droppable({        
    drop:function(event,ui){        
        addCategory(ui.draggable.html());       
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            header:'h3'
        });
    }
});


Category = function(item){
    var category = $("<h3><a href='#'>"+item+"</a></h3> \
                      <div> \
                      <p>hello I am accordion</p> \
                      </div>");
    return category;
}

function addCategory(item) {
    var category = Category(item);
    $('#accordion').append(category);
}
```

only the first drag li gets the accordion afterwards no class is added

I also used addClass('ui-accordion') on category object but still not working

plz help I can't figure it out

http://jsfiddle.net/ZXYrx/

below is the screenshot of what i want

[image]

Comment: I formatted your code, it was a bit of a mess

Comment: You've done it at least once before or your rate would be 0 :) just click on the 'V' next to the answer of a question you asked.

Comment: Hey but plz answer this question

Comment: Provide a jsFiddle please, so we can see what's going wrong and try to fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Test if work: add `$("#accordion").accordion("destroy");` before  `$( "#accordion" ).accordion({` in `drop` function

Comment: thanks alex it worked,can u write this as answer so that I can accept it

Comment: Ok, good ... Is the same as Kostantin ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to recreate the accordion on each drop, so do the following:

```
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion('destroy').accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        header:'h3'
    });
```

If destroy removes your content, then take it first `var html = $('#accordion').html();` and then destroy. Afterwards set the content before recreating.

Comment: I added destroy just below $('#accordion').append(category); and its working good

Answer (score 0):

Ok... is the same as Kostantin say, by the way, you need to detroy and recreacte the accordion:

like:

```
$( ".dropArea" ).droppable({        
    drop:function(event,ui){        
        addCategory(ui.draggable.html());       
        $( '#accordion' ).accordion( "detroy" ); // <-- destroy
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            header:'h3'
        });
    }
});
```